# How can I get Arabic report using itextsharp

Tags: asp.net, itext

I used this tutorial:

> http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-ASPNet-Web-Page-with-images-to-PDF-using-ITextsharp.aspx

to convert my page to a pdf report, but when I use Arabic characters in HTML code, I get empty an report. I think iTextsharp can't decode Arabic language; for example, I write this:

```
<tr><td>نام</td><td>Age</td></tr>
<tr><td>John</td><td>11</td></tr>
```

When i use Arabic, in- and output show me empty cells. How can i solve that?

Comment: There's no good way to do it now. See a workaround [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362152/arabic-caracters-in-html-to-pdf-using-itext).

Comment: check this question that may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080741/convert-arabicunicode-content-html-or-xml-to-pdf-using-itextsharp